# How to send ViewBag to other RenderPage using other RenderPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

What I want to do is to send a `ViewBag` from first `RenderPage()` to other `RenderPage()`.

In `_Layout.cshtml` I have 3 render called:

```
@RenderPage("FirstRenderPage")
@RenderBody() //Never mind this one
@RenderPage("SecondRenderPage")
```

In `FirstRenderPage` I have a `ViewBag`:

```
@ViewBag.Messages = "Hello, World"
```

and In `SecondRenderPage` I need to show the messages:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Messages</h1>
```

but the problem is the `SecondRenderpage` dint received the messages.

Comment: **Not Sure** .. i don't think `ViewBag` will work here .. you can try using `TempData` instead.

Comment: @Kartikeya I can do that, but the problem is if I go to that solution it will give another problem to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RenderPage()` has an optional second argument `params object[] data` that can be used to pass additional data (in your case `ViewBag.Mesages`) to the view. [Refer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.renderpage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: yes, but the `ViewBag.Messages` is inside the first render pages? so how can I add the parameter like this `@RenderPage("SecondRenderPage", ViewBag.Messages)`?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood where you were assigning the ViewBag property. Since your using `@RenderPage` AFAIK, you cant because you don't have access to the pages `ViewDataDictionary`. You would need to assign the values in the main view.